# Result of calling web3.version.getNetwork() from browser-side code is always undefined?

Tags: web3js, metamask, network

I'm trying to get the network ID from the Web3 object on the client side (i.e. - while running Javascript code in the browser).  I have code that confirms that the object exists and it does.  I have the Metamask extension installed and configured in Chrome.  I have clicked on the extension and I am definitely connected to the Ganache network client (Localhost 8545).  However, every time I call `**web3.version.getNetwork()**` the result is `**undefined**`.  Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

UPDATE: I tried the same test with **web3.eth.getAccounts()** and that too is coming back *undefined*.  I'm guessing I'll get the same result with any of the Web3 methods/properties I try.

```
    // Make sure the Web3.js object has been defined.
    web3_helpers.web3AndMetamaskCheck();

    if (typeof gameDetailsObj == 'undefined' || gameDetailsObj == null)
        throw new Error(errPrefix + 'The game details object is unassigned.');

    if (typeof currentUserObj == 'undefined' || currentUserObj == null)
        throw new Error(errPrefix + 'The current user object is unassigned.');

    // >>>>> getNetworkCall is ALWAYS 'undefined'.          
    var getNetworkCall = web3.version.getNetwork();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your right it will return undefined. Because web3.version.getNetwork() is not a sync method and it will not return any value. In javascript, If function is not return any method it will init varible is undefined. Refer below code for ref:

```
web3.version.getNetwork(function(err, networkId){
            switch(networkId){
                case "1":
                    //TODO your logic...
                    break;
                default:
                    //If neteork id is not mattching...
            }
});
```